# Compare data types of two columns of different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have two different tables A and B and want to copy data from table A to table B but only after matching the datatypes and key constraints (like primary key) of two columns. If the data type and key constraints matches, then only copy data from column of table A to same column of table B, otherwise copy that data to third table i.e. error_log table and also mentioning the error in errorvalue column.

I am checking the data types as below:

```
SELECT C.NAME AS COLUMN_NAME,
       TYPE_NAME(C.USER_TYPE_ID) AS DATA_TYPE,
FROM SYS.COLUMNS C
WHERE C.OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID('table A');
```

Table structures look like as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tableA](
    [CustomerId] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Housenumber] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Visit Id] [nvarchar](max) NULL,      ---primary key
    [Zipcode] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [City] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Visit Date] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Duration] [nvarchar](max) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tableB](
        [CustomerId] [nvarchar](2000) NULL,
        [Housenumber] [nvarchar](2000) NULL,
        [Visit Id] [nvarchar](2000) NULL,      
        [Zipcode] [nvarchar](2000) NULL,
        [City] [nvarchar](2000) NULL,
        [Visit Date] [datetime] NULL,
        [Duration] [float](max) NULL,
        [Counter 1] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
        [Counter 2] [nvarchar](100) NULL 
    ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[error_log](
        [CustomerId] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [Housenumber] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [Visit Id] [nvarchar](max) NULL,      ---primary key
        [Zipcode] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [City] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [Visit Date] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [Duration] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [errorvalue] [nvarchar](max) NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Can anybody suggest how can I compare data types and do this task with the help of **stored procedure**.

Comment: Please provide some example table structures and sample data to better illustrate what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @DaleK I have provided the table structures.

Comment: I hope this could help: https://github.com/bendaland/jda-mssql-helpers/blob/master/table.datatype.comparisons.sql

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough to compare the data type alone.
If it's `nvarchar`/`nchar`/`varchar`/`char`/`varbinary`/`binary` data you also need to compare the maximum allowed length,
if it's a `date`/`time`/`datetime2`/`datetimeoffset` you need to compare scale. 
and if it's a `decimal`/`numeric` you need to compare both scale and precision.

To check the key constraints you need to query two more tables - `sys.indexes` and `sys.index_columns`.

Lucky for you, You don't have to write the entire thing yourself, as I've already done a lot of that work before for [my latest blog post.](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2020/02/06/t-sql-crud-procedures-auto-generator/)

The relevant part of the code is in the beginning of the script, where I populate a table I use later on to build dynamic SQL from - here's the select statement (I've added aliases to make it easy to understand):

```
SELECT  col.Name As ColumnName, 
        typ.Name As TypeName,
        CAST(col.max_length as nvarchar(11)) As MaxLength, 
        IIF(typ.name IN ('nvarchar', 'nchar', 'varchar', 'char', 'varbinary', 'binary'), 1, 0) As IncludeMaxLength, 
        IIF(idx.is_primary_key = 1, 1, 0) As IsPkColumn,
        col.is_identity As IsIdentity,
        col.is_computed As IsComputed,
        SIGN(/*col.generated_always_type*/0) As IsAutoGenerated, 
        IIF(typ.name IN('numeric', 'decimal'), 1, 0) As IncludePrecisionAndScale,
        col.[precision],
        IIF(typ.name IN('datetimeoffset', 'datetime2', 'time'), 1, 0) As IncludeScale,
        col.scale
FROM sys.columns as col
JOIN sys.types As typ
    ON  col.system_type_id = typ.system_type_id 
    AND col.user_type_id = typ.user_type_id 
JOIN sys.tables as tab
    ON col.object_id = tab.object_id 
LEFT JOIN sys.index_columns idxCol
    ON  col.object_id = idxCol.object_id 
    AND idxCol.column_id = col.column_id
LEFT JOIN sys.indexes idx
    ON  idx.object_id = tab.object_id 
    AND idxCol.index_id = idx.index_id
WHERE tab.name = @TableName
```

You can run this query on both tables and compare any relevant data for any column in the tables.